# Finding general formula for this recursion function

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, sequence

I have a recursion relation defined as

```
Clear[f];
f[x_] := 0 /; 0 <= x < π/3;
f[x_] := x - π/3 /; π/3 <= x < 2 π/3;
f[x_] := f[x - 2 π/3] + π/3 /; x >= 2 π/3;
f[x_] := -f[π/3 - x] /; x < 0;

Plot[f[x], {x,-2Pi,2Pi}, Ticks->{Range[-2π,2π,π/2], Automatic}]
```

[image]

I'm unsure of where to go from here to find the solution. `RSolve` seems doesn't worked.

How to use Mathematica to find it?

Comment: Maybe `h[x_] := Max[Mod[x, 2/3 \[Pi]] - \[Pi]/3, 0] + 
  Quotient[x, 2/3 \[Pi]] \[Pi]/3` ?

Comment: ... Is this a math question or a Mathematica question? The answers here give "the mathematical result", not "how to use Mathematica to find it".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f2[x_] := If[EvenQ[#], # π/6, (# - 1) π /6 + #2] & @@ QuotientRemainder[x, π/3];

Plot[{f2[x], f[x]}, {x, -2 π, 2 π}, 
 Ticks -> {Range[-2 π, 2 π, π/3], Automatic},  
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[.7], Thickness[.01], Red], 
   Directive[Black, Dashed]}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes... but how did you *find* this function?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, by squinting (really hard, unfortunately):)