# Piecewise-constant function with infinitely many pieces

Tags: function-construction, piecewise

How can I define [the following function](https://mathoverflow.net/a/292733/34461) in Mathematica:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x-n,&\mbox{when $2n\le x\le 2n+1$,}\\n+1,&\mbox{when $2n+1\le x\le 2n+2$,}\end{cases}$$

where $n$ takes all integer values?

I tried this:

```
F[x_] := Piecewise[{
     {x - n, 2 n <= 2 <= 2 n + 1}, 
     {n + 1, 2 n + 1 <= x <= 2 n + 2}}]
```

But this apparently defines $F$ as a function of $n$, while I need it only as a function of $x$.

Comment: Related link: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163330/finding-general-formula-for-this-recursion-function

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That $F$ should really be something like $F_n$, defining a family of functions and then your total $F$ would really be the union of the $\{F_n\}$ over the domains where they are non-zero.

Then unless I am much mistaken each of those domains will have length $2$ and so we can define your family of functions as you had above and then have a dispatcher function to the appropriate function be your union function, using [`Quotient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quotient.html)

So in total it will look like:

```
fxn[x_, n_] :=
  Piecewise[
   {
    {x - n, 2 n <= x <= 2 n + 1},
    {n + 1, 2 n + 1 <= x <= 2 n + 2}
    }
   ];
fxn[x_] :=
 fxn[x, Quotient[x, 2]]
```

And we'll confirm that I have this right:

```
With[{maxN = 10},
 {
  Plot[
   Evaluate@Table[fxn[x, n], {n , 0, maxN}], {x, 0, 2*maxN + 2}],
  Plot[fxn[x], {x, 0, 2*maxN + 2}]
  }
 ]
```

[image: funion]

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand also how to solve similar problems.

Answer (score 17):

#### ***"...  I need it only as a function of x"***

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_] := Min[x - Quotient[x, 2], 1 + Quotient[x, 2]]

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 10}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 50}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

One more way is as follows.

```
f[x_] := Sum[ Piecewise[{{x - n, 2 n <= x <= 2 n + 1}, {n + 1, 
2 n + 1 <= x <= 2 n + 2}}], {n, -Infinity, Infinity}];
Plot[f[x],  {x, -4, 5}]
```

Answer (score 7):

Another way:

```
ftw[x_] = (TriangleWave[x/2 - 1/4] + 2 x + 1)/4
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem with your approach is that your [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise) definition depends on both `x` and `n`. However, given an `x` value one can compute what the corresponding `n` is, so the following [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise) function does what you want:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[
    {
    {x - Floor @ Quotient[x, 2], Mod[x, 2]<=1}
    },
    Floor @ Quotient[x, 2] + 1
]
```

where I used the fact that `n` can be derived from `x` using [`Floor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Floor) and [`Quotient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quotient). Here's a visualization:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]